# Android: get current device location without asking permission at run time

Tags: android, location

I've created a hospital related app where i want to know the whether patient has visited the doctor or not, getting the location is the requirement of my app.

I've used ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest. The problem is whenever application tries to get the location at run time the system prompts a security dialog  which says "this app is trying to obtain your current location" and asks user to allow or deny it,, and if user clicks on the deny button the location is not fetched..

I don't want the user to click on the deny button is there any way i can skip this security dialog and set 'always allow' option in my app permission through code and get the location without ever prompting the user for access.

[image]

manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kaizen"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="com.kaizen.volley.VolleySingleton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kaizen.SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kaizen.Login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.kaizen.AppMenu"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.kaizen.SignUp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

</application>
```

Comment: On which Android version does this happen?

Comment: i'm testing on jelly bean

Comment: Never seen that on jelly been. Once the gps/location is on the user will never be asked for anything.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of this popup ?

Comment: @Blackbelt screenshot is added.

Comment: it is pretty strange. Can you post your manifest ?

Comment: @Blackbelt why dear. why it is strange, does'nt this happen on jelly bean, i'm running the app on jelly bean 4.2.2 – i have posted the manifest

Comment: can you remove the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and try again ?

Comment: I alreasy did this.. on removing ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  this security alert disappears.

Comment: is the location service in the settings disabled ?

Comment: no. I have checked "Access to my location" and Wi-Fi & mobile network location" in the settings.

Comment: @Andrain have you checked your app to the other device because this should not generally happnes. if it no happenes to all other device then possibally In case of the custumized android device os may manifecturer provided the additional security and also i think you can change this security settings from the setting menu security section 

Once check and let me know 

I am too desparet to know this how this happned 

thanks

Comment: @sandy yes sure i will let you know. Right now I don't have any other  device.  security section does not show anything like enabling or disabling location. i f you want i can add the screen shot of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog you're seeing surely is a vendor specific feature. E.g. there is some function called KNOX for Samsung business devices, that seems to behave like what you're seeing. Once you found out where it comes from exactly, I wouldn't care about it any further. This is not widely spread and in those cases where the message pops up it will do for a reason: the user wants (or is forced by his administrator) to be informed about certain actions, such as apps wanting to get the current location.

You may check the normal behavior of your app in an emulator, if you do not have another device.

Comment: emulator does not show anything like this. ok is there any way I can know about what user has selected? I want to know if the user has pressed the allow button or deny button

Comment: If the current location is required by your app, then you should always handle the case where the location could not be retrieved, which can happen for different reasons. This will also apply in the situation, where the user presses 'Deny' on a device like yours. But again, you do not have to handle the specific dialog you're seeing. As you also can see from the comments above, this is not a common feature. I have a widely used location based app myself and never came across it. This might be a bit different, if your app would be used ONLY on devices like yours (which one is it by the way?).

Comment: my app would be used only on this device. It is QTab 1100. an ways thank you so much for your answer. My problem is not solved I'm leaving it now.